# Free ASP.NET Ajax Image gallery

Tags: looking-for-a-script, asp.net, free, ajax

I am searching for a free script in ASP.NET(C# o VB.NET) and Ajax form image gallery, can you help me?

Comment: @paulmorriss - even standard ASP.NET components use Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Gallery Server Pro](http://www.galleryserverpro.com), if you use webmatrix you can find it in the "web gallery" it's easy to install.

Comment: Thank Murilo, one question: Gallery Server Pro, are free?

Comment: It's a free, open source application.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this one.

http://www.aspphotogallery.net/mvcphotogallery/

Might be easier to use, no database, it uses the folder structure of your images.

One thing, it's not free but it's license is fairly cheap.